# Consecutive animations using nested animation blocks

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiscrollview, uiimageview, objective-c-blocks

I'm looking for a way to implement consecutive animations using nested animation blocks.

Somewhat complicated by happening inside a UIScrollView, the size of three UIImageViews (there are many images, and as I scroll through them I constantly swapping out the images in the UIImageViews).

When a scroll is finished, I want to switch out the image in the (visible) middle UIImageView, three times, then back to the original view. I'm trying it thus:

```
- (void) doAnimation {
    // get the animation frames, along with the current image
    NSString *swap1 = @"first.png";
    NSString *swap2 = @"second.png";
    UIImage *original = currentPage.image;

    UIViewAnimationOptions myOptions = UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:2.0 options:myOptions
            animations:^{ [currentPage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:swap1]]; }
            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:2.0 options:myOptions
                        animations:^{ [currentPage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:swap2]]; }
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:2.0 options:myOptions
                                    animations:^{ [currentPage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:swap1]]; }
                                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                        [currentPage setImage:original]; }]; }]; }];
}
```

When I run this, there is no duration, no delay, it all happens at once, almost too fast for the eye to see. Could this be because "currentPage" is a UIImageView? (Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138927/uiview-animatewithdurationdelay-working-weird)?)

Comment: Did you consider using UIImageView's "animationImages" property?

Comment: Why are you delaying if you are firing the animation in the completion blocks?

Comment: **Re: animationImages property**: I wanted more control over the durations, so that "swap2" lasted twice as long as "swap1". **Re: delaying**: I just put that in as a test - even with delay of 0.0, it's the duration that is not working (actually, I would like a duration of 0.0, with delays being active)

Comment: If you just want to control your timing over image swaps have you considered using the **NSObject** method: performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: instead of nested animation blocks?

Comment: I eventually did end up using UIImageView's "animationImages" property, as @magma suggested, after realizing I have control over the durations of image swaps by repeating images in an array: `[swap1, swap2, swap2, swap2, swap2, swap1, nil];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no delay because `UIImageView.image` isn't an animateable property. As such, the UIView animation machinery will have no animations to set up and will just call your completion block immediately.

What sort of animation did you expect? You can attach a `CATransition` object to the underlying layer to get a simple cross-fade, Just use `[imageView.layer addAnimation:[CATransition animation] forKey:nil]` to get the crossfade with the default values (you can customize the timing by modifying properties of the CATransition before attaching it to the layer). To achieve the subsequent animations, you can either use the `delegate` property of `CAAnimation` (`CATransition`'s superclass) to learn when it's done and fire your second one, or you could just use `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` to start your next animation step after a user-defined delay. The delegate method is going to be more accurate with regards to timing, but the performSelector method is a bit easier to write. Sadly, CAAnimation doesn't support a completion block.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer (the only answer too!) because Kevin is of course correct that UIImageView.image is not an animatable property; it is the reason why there was "no duration, no delay, it all happens at once".

Comment: @coco: If you were hoping to simply get control over when the images swap out, but don't want a cross-fade, you should look at [CAKeyframeAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html). This lets you specify an array of values and times (and timing functions), though I'm not sure how it behaves for a non-animateable property (e.g. it might just do nothing) which is why I didn't suggest it before.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for you to transition from one image view to another is by using the block animation function [transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView%3aduration%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a) as discussed in "[Creating Animated Transitions Between Views"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html). You would do this instead of animateWithDuration to change images.